# android activity block user interactions

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I temporarily block all user interactions with the views of an activity ?
(Other than calling the setEnabled method on each view)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to block user interaction while performing some task in the background you can use a ProgressDialog.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog

Comment: From the page you linked: "Avoid ProgressDialog
 Android includes another dialog class called ProgressDialog that shows a dialog with a progress bar. However, if you need to indicate loading or indeterminate progress, you should instead follow the design guidelines for Progress & Activity and use a ProgressBar in your layout."

Answer (score 0):

As Stefan allready wrote. As long as you are showing a ProgressDialog the user can't interact with the views in your activity. If you set the dialog to cancelable false even the back button is deactivated.